# create nodes / relationship pointing to the same city

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an empty neo4j database. I want the city{val:"new york"} node to only have one instance, not two.  What is the correct way to CREATE these nodes and relationships so that john and sam are pointing to the same city{val:"new york"} node?

```
CREATE
(p:person{name:"john"}),
(c:city{val:"new york"}),
(p)-[:LIVES_IN]->(c)

CREATE
(p:person{name:"sam"}),
(c:city{val:"new york"}),
(p)-[:LIVES_IN]->(c)
```

The data I am importing is in a csv file.  I need some way to only create the city if it does not already exist.  I tried to replace CREATE with MERGE, but the syntax is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler (and safer, since you don't always know if the data already exists) to just always use `MERGE` in cases where there can be duplicate attempts to create data that you want to be unique.

These 2 blocks of Cypher statements will not create duplicate nodes/relationships, even if you reverse the order (or if the DB already has some of the same data).

```
MERGE (p:person{name:"john"})
MERGE (c:city{val:"new york"})
MERGE (p)-[:LIVES_IN]->(c);

MERGE (p:person{name:"sam"})
MERGE (c:city{val:"new york"})
MERGE (p)-[:LIVES_IN]->(c);
```

Comment: Adding this here for other neo neo4j people.   https://neo4j.com/blog/common-confusions-cypher/

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.  Each line needs its own MERGE clause.

```
CREATE
(p:person{name:"john"}),
(c:city{val:"new york"}),
(p)-[:LIVES_IN]->(c)

MERGE (p:person{name:"sam"})
MERGE (c:city{val:"new york"})
MERGE (p)-[:LIVES_IN]->(c)
```

Good related resource...https://neo4j.com/blog/common-confusions-cypher/

Comment: You can also use `MERGE` the first three patterns (john, new york + lives_in).